# Showing the wrong data for SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my query

```sql
SELECT a.ID, DATEDIFF(b.PaymentDate, a.ReservationDate) AS 'DIF'
FROM Reservation a, Payment b
WHERE a.ID = b.ID
AND DATEDIFF(a.ReservationDate, b.PaymentDate) <= 10;
```

The query should print the ID for those records where the difference of `Reservation date` and `Payment date` is less than or equal to 10 days. Both dates are using the same entry format of `YEAR-MM-DD`. I have 5 test entries for the question and all 5 appear when I run it. However, only 1 of the 5 falls into the criteria so I'm confused why it is happening.

But it just prints all the results regardless.

Does anyone know what the issue is?

EDIT: Here is the data being entered,

```sql
insert into Reservation values('R321','2020-6-12');
insert into Reservation values('R310','2020-5-22');
insert into Reservation values('R421','2020-7-25');
insert into Reservation values('R222','2020-4-10');
insert into Reservation values('R201','2020-3-15');

insert into Payment values('P300','R321','2020-6-13');
insert into Payment values('P301','R310','2020-8-15');
insert into Payment values('P302','R421','2020-9-20');
insert into Payment values('P303','R222','2020-9-10');
insert into Payment values('P304','R201','2020-10-10');
```

AND here are the tables

```
 create table Payment(
     PaymentID char(4) primary key,
     ID char(4),
     PaymentDate date,
     foreign key (ID) references Reservation (ID)
 );

 create table Reservation(
     ID char(4) primary key,
     ReservationDate date,
 );
```

Comment: Please add your sample data with table schema also in the question

Comment: @AkhileshMishra I have added the data requested, :)

Comment: What results do you get? In you select clause you've got the dates the wrong way around. Should be payment second,

Comment: If the first parameter of DATEDIFF is an earlier date than the second one, the diff result gets negative. And in your where condition, the reservation date is always earlier than the payment date, thus the diff is negative and of course also <= 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are calculating the difference of `Reservation Date` and `Payment Date` which will be negative. That's why you are getting all the records. You should calculate the difference of `Payment Date` and `Reservation Date` in where clause like below :

```
SELECT 
a.ID, 
DATEDIFF(b.PaymentDate, a.ReservationDate) AS 'DIF'
FROM Reservation a, Payment b
WHERE a.ID = b.ID
AND DATEDIFF( b.PaymentDate, a.ReservationDate) <= 10;
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=1b0ba7356357f21b4164e438775ae044)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the complete and concise example.

You have reversed the DATEDIFF params in the where clause and the one you are selecting.

Try this

```
SELECT a.ID, DATEDIFF(b.PaymentDate, a.ReservationDate) AS 'DIF'
  FROM Reservation a, Payment b
 WHERE a.ID = b.ID
   AND DATEDIFF(b.PaymentDate, a.ReservationDate) <= 10;



+------+-----+
|  ID  | DIF |
+------+-----+
| R321 |   1 |
+------+-----+
```

dbfiddle link
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=3ae37d0e7523c6280dda80693471bdb7